# Can Fragment act like MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, wifi-direct

**Project1**
I have created a app that scans nearby wifidirect enabled devices whose UI was simple and had only one layout(activitymain.xml) and the code was in MainActivity.java & WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver. (Code can be found here: [Can't find nearby WiFi- Direct devices showing "No Device Found!"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68117249/11024854))

**Project2**
Now, I want to use Tablayout(custom not from default) which contains 2 tabs so I have to use 2 fragments.
Where should I place the code that was in MainActivity(project1)?
should I copy to fragment1 or MainActivity(Project2)

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the code of MainActivity (project1) to fragment of the tabbed layout. And then configure the SectionPagerAdapter like below.

Also you have to change some code of your MainActivity so that it gets fitted into the fragment.

```
private val TAB_TITLES = arrayOf(
    R.string.tab_text_1,
    R.string.tab_text_2
)

/**
* A [FragmentPagerAdapter] that returns a fragment corresponding to
* one of the sections/tabs/pages.
*/
class SectionsPagerAdapter(private val context: Context, fm: FragmentManager)
: FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    var fragment: Fragment? = null

    when (position) {
        0 -> fragment = Fragment1("f1","f1")
        1 -> fragment = Fragment2("f2","f2")
    }

    return fragment!!
}

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    return context.resources.getString(TAB_TITLES[position])
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    // Show 2 total pages.
    return 2
}
}
```

You can create fragments like this:

```
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

class Fragment1 : Fragment() {
   private var param1: String? = null
   private var param2: String? = null

   private var _binding: Fragment1Binding? = null
   private val binding get() = _binding!!


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root

    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}


override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
}


override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
}

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            HomeFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
}
}
```

You can make Fragment2 like this and attach this to your tabbed layout.

Comment: Is this answer works for you? If yes then please accept it. Otherwise tell me your problem.

Comment: But there is some code in methods onPause() and onResume() in MainActivity(Project1) how can I copy them to fragment? (as far as I know fragments have different lifecycles)

Comment: fragments also has onPause and onResume method in it. so you can copy that codes to them.

Comment: I have updated the answer for how to create the fragment. You can take that as your reference. If satisfied, Please accept the answer. :)